# Draw a random sample from two dimensional KDE distribution

Tags: kde-plasma

I used seaborn and genereated a two dimentional KDE and hope to draw a random sample from KDE. How could I do this? I learned that seaborn kde cannot do this. Is this correct. If so, how could I get a random sample from 2D KDE? many thanks!

I found this answer on stackoverlflow but do not understand the meaning of line kde = gaussian_kde(X.T)... what does T mean?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# random 2d values
X = np.random.randn(1000, 2)

# fit kernel density estimate. needs to be transposed for the function
kde = gaussian_kde(X.T)

# now you can resample from it
# transpose to have same shape as X
Y = kde.resample(1000).T
```

Answer (score 0):

For the X.T part, it is simply to do the transpose of X array. From `X = np.random.randn(1000, 2)`, you will get a (1000,2) array. Next, you do X.T to transpose the X into a (2,1000) array, which is the necessary for using `gaussian_kde()`

For resampling from a 2D KDE, you can refer to [kalepy](https://kalepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multi-dimensional-kernel-density-estimation). They provide several clear and simple examples on how to do it.